# How to drawing vertical line in left of text paragraph on pdf page using itext5

Tags: pdf, text, itext, line, drawing

How to drawing vertical line in left of text paragraph on pdf page using iText5.
I can use left paragraph border, but if on textline 2, 3 ... of bullet numbering the vertical line are not folow the position of text (left pic)

I think, will solved if I drawing vertical line per textline paragraph (line by line), but I don't know What must I do first....

And maybe have any solution....

Result on pic (right pic)

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you attach your current code you have so far? Also, any reason not to switch to iText 7? iText 5 has been long deprecated

Comment: sorry, i don't have code for this. Can you give me code for this

Comment: Generally the StackOverflow community asks for your current code to see what you have already tried, what your current result is and what is the desired result. Currently we see screenshots from Word but not the screenshots of the result produced by your code. It's okay if your code does not draw the vertical line on the left as you wish  and just draws a paragraph. Also, what about the "why not iText 7" part of my question?

Comment: I use iText5 because free